# How to find matching elements from array and do further processing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

i am building request for the backend so trying to create two arrays one that matches indexId in request and other that is not matched. so i can build request for both array separately calling `this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, matchingArray)`

main.ts

```
   for (const rxInfo of this.rxInfos) {
        const member = specialtyMembers.find((memberData) => memberData.indexID ===
            rxInfo.indexID);
        if (member) {
            this.indexIDs.push(rxInfo.indexID);
            proxyMember = member;
            if (!member.dateOfBirth) {
                statusDesc = "member dateOfbirth not found";
                return Promise.reject(this.errorHandler(request, statusDesc));
            }
            const tempArray: any = this.rxInfos;
            const matchingArray: any = [];
            const unmatched: any = [];
            tempArray.forEach((element: any) => {
                if (element.indexID === rxInfo.IndexID) {
                    matchingArray.push(rxInfo);
                } else {
                  unmatched.push(rxInfo) 
                }
            })
// this method should call for both matchingArray and unmatchedArray 
            const requestBody: any = this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, matchingArray);
            const requestObject = this.specialtyQuestionRequest(requestBody);
            this.requestArray.push(requestObject);
        } else {
            this.mismatchIndexIDS.push(rxInfo.indexID);
            this.indexIdMismatchCounter++;
        }
    }

  private buildSingleRequestBody(specialtyMember: any, rxInfo: any) {

        return {
            "specialtyID":"1234",
            "sourceSystem": "test",
            "rxInfos": rxInfo,
            "dateOfBirth": "1956-07-12",

        };
    }
```

data

```
{
    "rxInfos": [
        {
            "drugNdc": "00004080085",
            "rxNumber": "1459004",
            "indexID":"HGYIIITTS=="
        },
            {
            "drugNdc": "00004080085",
            "rxNumber": "144500004",
            "indexID":"HGYIIITTS=="
        },
        {
            "drugNdc": "00004080085",
            "rxNumber": "1677004",
            "indexID":"HGTHJJSKK=="
        }
    ]
}
```

Output from buildSingleRequestBody for each array

```
unmatched request {
    "specialtyID": "1234",
    "sourceSystem": "test",
    "dateOfBirth": "1956-07-12",
    "rxInfos": [{
            "drugNdc": "00004080085",
            "rxNumber": "1677004",
            "indexID": "HGTHJJSKK=="
        }

    ]
}

matched array requerst 
{
    "specialtyID": "1234",
    "sourceSystem": "test",
    "dateOfBirth": "1956-07-12",
    "rxInfos": [{
            "drugNdc": "00004080085",
            "rxNumber": "1459004",
            "indexID": "HGYIIITTS=="
        },
        {
            "drugNdc": "00004080085",
            "rxNumber": "144500004",
            "indexID": "HGYIIITTS=="
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I'ts not very clear what you're asking

Comment: You seem to be adding the different objects & indexes into the different arrays, so what is your current problem? Can you describe more what is going wrong?

Comment: i got stuck how to call `buildSingleRequestBody` for each of match/unmatch arrays its calling for matchingArrays for now

Comment: @Icepickle added `buildSingleRequestBody` method to understand expected result

Comment: I honestly still don't get the problem you seem to be having :( I find it interesting to see it is typescript, and then you are using `any` type in almost all places :)

Comment: @Icepickle these is just initial code i will have interfaces later , i wanted to call `buildSingleRequestBody` for both matched/unmatched array separately

Comment: And, what is stopping you from doing that? Do you want to create an array of 2 objects of the matched / unmatched results of buildSingleRequestBody, do you want to concatenate the input for buildSingleRequestBody, do you want to add a third argument to the methods, so you can distinguish between matched and unmatched on the endpoint where you eventually be sending your request to?

Comment: building request so each request will have match and unmatched array so i can call backend . buidlSingleRequest would just create request for each array

Comment: Once again, I don't really see what is stopping you, you can do something like `const requestBody: any = [ this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, matchingArray), this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, unmatched)];`, but in all honesty, when you have written this code already, I don't see how you can be stuck where you are now...

Comment: @Icepickle thats where i got stuck i dont want to call simultaneously both array one at a time so i can get separate requestBody for each array

Comment: I would like to say "beats me", but in the spirit of being welcoming, can you give the expected output of your single request function?

Comment: @Icepickle i added expected output thanks for helping

Comment: But okay, that's the thing, you can just send 3 parameters to buildSingleRequest and then build an array from there, once again, I don't really see where your problem might be